# R How to get desired rows in aggregation using data.table and dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Suppose we have a data set like:

```
X = data.frame(
  ID = 1:9,
  DRIVE_NUM = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
  FLAG =c("PASS","FAIL","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","FAIL","FAIL")
  )

ID DRIVE_NUM FLAG
 1         A PASS
 2         A FAIL
 3         A PASS
-----------------
 4         B PASS
 5         B PASS
 6         B PASS
-----------------
 7         C PASS
 8         C FAIL
 9         C FAIL
```

I want to aggregate this data set by DRIVE_NUM by the following rule:

> For a specific DRIVE_NUM group,
>
> If there is any FAIL flag in the DRIVE_NUM group, I want the first row
>   with the FAIL flag.
>
> If there is no FAIL flag in the group, just take the first row in the
>   group.

So, I shall get the following set:

```
wanted = data.frame(
  ID = c(2,4,8),
  DRIVE_NUM = c("A","B","C"),
  FLAG = c("FAIL","PASS","FAIL")
  )

  ID DRIVE_NUM FLAG
   2         A FAIL
   4         B PASS
   8         C FAIL
```

Now I could do it using ddply but it's extremely slow since my data set is usually very big.

Is there any way to do it using data.table or dplyr.

---

Update:

It seems that dplyr is even slower than plyr. Is there any way to do anything faster than plyr. Or am I using anything inappropirately?

```
#Simulate Data

X = data.frame(
  group = rep(paste0("NO",1:10000),each=2),
  flag = sample(c("F","P"),20000,replace = TRUE),
  var = rnorm(20000)
)



library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

#plyr

START = proc.time()
X2 = ddply(X,.(flag),function(df) {
  if( sum(df$flag=="F")> 0){
    R = df[df$flag=="F",]
    if(nrow(R)>1) {R = R[1,]} else {R = R}
  } else{
    R = df[1,]
  }
  R
})
proc.time() - START   

#user  system elapsed 
#0.03    0.00    0.03 

#dplyr method 1

START = proc.time()
X %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice(which.min(flag))
proc.time() - START  

#user  system elapsed 
#0.22    0.02    0.23 

#dplyr method 2

START = proc.time()
X %>%
  group_by(group, flag) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice(which.min(flag))
proc.time() - START  

#user  system elapsed 
#0.28    0.00    0.28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we only ever want the first row for each `DRIVE_NUM`:`FLAG` combination, we start by selecting only those first rows using `group_by` and `slice`. Then we make sure we arrange by `FLAG`, so if there is a `FAIL` it will be the top row for that `DRIVE_NUM`, but if there is only a `PASS`, then nothing changes. Then we `slice` again to select that top row.

```
library(dplyr)
X %>%
  group_by(DRIVE_NUM, FLAG) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(DRIVE_NUM) %>% 
  slice(which.min(FLAG))
```

@Frank basically solved this much shorter, relying on `which.min` taking the first value (first row).

```
X %>%
  group_by(DRIVE_NUM) %>% 
  slice(which.min(FLAG))
```

Comment: Oh, right. It did test it on their data and got the correct result, but somehow missed that. It still works since alphabetical order will be used.

Comment: Yes, excellent. Thanks. I tend to forget that `which.min` takes the first value.